# formatting csv file before writing

Tags: vb.net

I want to write data in csv file using vb.net.

So before writing the data i want to format the cell to text.

how to do this?

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to do with proper examples. Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you store it as ="1110123.2101008210" excel will store it as text. Make sure not to leave any space preceding the equals sign.

for example: "data",="1110123.2101008210","more data"

Answer (score 0):

you can try *object*.ToString() or Ctype(object, String)

Replace object with the thing you want to write, i.e. the variable.

Comment: i able to write the data but it does not fully display it...i want to write something like this 1110123.2101008210..it only displays 1110123.2101008...so before writing i want to format the cell to text

Comment: are you viewing the data in Excel? If so, its probably a formatting issue. Try opening your file in Notepad first, if you do see all your data, then go back to excel and change the format of the cells.

Comment: i do see all the data in notepad but i want to format the csv file in vb.net before writing the data so that all the data gets displayed when i open the csv file

Comment: I don't think you can embed formatting information in a CSV for Excel. At an absolute minimum, you could place a ' in front of your numeric data, but the ' character will be visible in Excel. I tried saving a CSV from Excel, and it ended up truncating my decimal places as well. If formatting is important to you, you could always generate an excel file with html.

Comment: @sheron did you give my solution a shot?